# Java and MSSQL problems with getting data from database

Tags: java, mysql

Okay im getting a bit confused atm, im trying to retrieve some data from a datebase using java and mssql.

In sql i write this:

```
use MyChamp SELECT * 
FROM [GROUP]
 JOIN Team on [Group].GroupID = Team.GroupID
 JOIN Match on Team.TeamID = HomeTeamID
WHERE [GROUP].GroupID = 9
```

and it work.

In java my string to execute looks like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM [GROUP]"
                + "JOIN Team on [Group].GroupID = Team.GroupID"
                + "JOIN Match on Team.TeamID = HomeTeamID"
                + "WHERE [GROUP].GroupID = 9"
                + "ORDER BY MatchRound:";
```

It does not work i get sql error msg saying:

```
Error: S0001Incorrect syntax near 'Match'.
```

but i cant find the error :(

Comment: you forgot the spaces..

Comment: The "order by matchRound isnt nesseary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put spaces after string termination quote "

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM [GROUP] "
                + "JOIN Team on [Group].GroupID = Team.GroupID "
                + "JOIN Match on Team.TeamID = HomeTeamID "
                + "WHERE [GROUP].GroupID = 9 "
                + "ORDER BY MatchRound "
```

If you don't your string will be generated like this.

```
SELECT * FROM [GROUP]JOIN Team on [Group].GroupID = Team.GroupIDJOIN Match on Team.TeamID = HomeTeamIDWHERE [GROUP].GroupID = 9ORDER BY MatchRound
```